# Problema com função para mostrar div's

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, estou com um problema que é o seguinte:
Quero que quando o utilizador clica num botão vai aparecer um div ou vários divs dependendo da pagina em que se encontra, mas a função só está a mostrar o primeiro div, mesmo usando id's diferentes.

```
 <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="about">
   <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Sobre a escola</h3>
      <?php
          $sql_sobre = "SELECT sobre_augusto1 FROM campos";
          $sql_sobrequery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_sobre) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
          $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_sobrequery);
          echo $row[0];
      ?><div id="edicao" hidden><code><b style="font-size:18px">Use &ltp&gt<i>exemplo de texto</i>&lt/p&gt quando quiser fazer um parágrafo.</b></code><form method="POST" action="confirmarEdicao.php"><textarea class="textboxEditar" name="edicaoSobreAugusto1"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></textarea> <input class="buttonEditar" type="submit" value="Confirmar"></form></div>
      <img src="planta.jpg" class="w3-image center">
      <?php
          $sql_sobre = "SELECT sobre_augusto2 FROM campos";
          $sql_sobrequery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_sobre) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
          $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_sobrequery);
          echo $row[0];
      ?><div id="edicao1" hidden><code><b style="font-size:18px">Use &ltp&gt<i>exemplo de texto</i>&lt/p&gt quando quiser fazer um parágrafo.</b></code><form method="POST" action="confirmarEdicao.php"><textarea class="textboxEditar" name="edicaoSobreAugusto2"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></textarea> <input class="buttonEditar" type="submit" value="Confirmar"></form></div>
  </div>
```

Os divs que eu quero que apareçam e desapareçam são os com 'id="edicao..."'.

A minha função em javascript é a seguinte:

```
function ativaredicao(){
    var x = document.getElementById("edicao");
    var y = document.getElementById("edicao1");
    if ((x.style.display === "none") || (y.style.display === "none"))  {
        x.style.display = "block";
        y.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
        y.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou as duas divs, muda o hidden por style="display:none", mas mesmo com hidden funcionou

Comment: Para mim continua só a aparecer a primeira

Comment: No Console do DevTools tem algum erro? E para testar remove o PHP e deixa apenas o HTML e o JS

Comment: tem 2 erros mas nao tem a ver com este código.
mesmo tirando o php continuo com o problema.

Comment: Se o erro for de JS ele para a execução dos scripts, se for algo como (Not Found) não tem problema

Comment: Tem um erro no JS mas é porque tem uma função no mesmo ficheiro, em que está a funçao ativaredicao(), que nao está a ser usado nesta página, isso importa?

Comment: Pode interferir, verifica se em um documento separado funciona, apenas o HTML e JS

Comment: Ok, separei as 2 funções em ficheiros diferentes e já funciona, obrigado pelo seu tempo!